# angular-universal setup throws "no metadata found"-exception with JIT-Compiler

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-universal

I am trying to get ngExpressEngine to work with the JIT compiler (Angular 4.1.X), but there is a problem. Why does the JIT need metadata?

- Angular version: 4.1.X
- Language: TypeScript 2.2
- OS: Mac OS X
- Platform: NodeJs

```
Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'MainModule'.
   at NgModuleResolver.resolve (/Users/matthias/Documents/private workspace/chaoslistapi/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13889:23)
   at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (/Users/matthias/Documents/private workspace/chaoslistapi/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14473:60)
   at JitCompiler._loadModules (/Users/matthias/Documents/private workspace/chaoslistapi/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:25640:66)
   at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (/Users/matthias/Documents/private workspace/chaoslistapi/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:25599:52)
   at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (/Users/matthias/Documents/private workspace/chaoslistapi/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:25561:23)
   at /Users/matthias/Documents/private workspace/chaoslistapi/node_modules/@nguniversal/express-engine/src/main.js:82:22
   at getFactory (/Users/matthias/Documents/private workspace/chaoslistapi/node_modules/@nguniversal/express-engine/src/main.js:68:12)
   at View.engine (/Users/matthias/Documents/private workspace/chaoslistapi/node_modules/@nguniversal/express-engine/src/main.js:46:13)
   at View.render (/Users/matthias/Documents/private workspace/chaoslistapi/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:126:8)
   at tryRender (/Users/matthias/Documents/private workspace/chaoslistapi/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:639:10)
   at Function.render (/Users/matthias/Documents/private workspace/chaoslistapi/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:591:3)
   at ServerResponse.render (/Users/matthias/Documents/private workspace/chaoslistapi/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:960:7)
```

Here is my server module

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router'

import { AppModule, AppComponent } from './app/app.module'
import { SharedModule } from './app/shared/shared.module'

import { BrowserModule, Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server'

export function getLRU() {
  return new Map()
}
export function getRequest() {
  return Zone.current.get('req') || {}
}
export function getResponse() {
  return Zone.current.get('res') || {}
}

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({
      appId: 'chaoslist'
    }),
    ServerModule,

    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([], { useHash: false }),

    SharedModule.forRoot(),
    AppModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: 'isBrowser', useValue: false },
    { provide: 'isNode', useValue: true },

    { provide: 'req', useFactory: getRequest },
    { provide: 'res', useFactory: getResponse },

    { provide: 'LRU', useFactory: getLRU, deps: [] },

    Meta
  ]
})

export class MainModule {

}
```

And my call to the ngExpressEngine. I found a commit where JIT integration was done so this should in theory work. Is this a new bug or did I do something blatantly wrong here?

```js
// Angular 2 Universal
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';

// App
import { MainModule } from './node.module';
// Express View
    this.app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
      bootstrap: MainModule
    }));
```